# Mongodb-Hadoop connector version error

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, sbt

I am trying to connect hadoop to mongodb on windows. I have the version 2.3 of Hadoop and I change the build.sbt file so I have this

```
hadoopRelease in ThisBuild := "2.3"
```

And yet when I try to run this command

```
sbt package
```

I keep getting this error message, despite the fact Hadoop is up and running with the 2.3 version.

```
[debug]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Hadoop Release '%s' is an invalid/unsupported releas
e.  Valid entries are in 2.3
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at MongoHadoopBuild$$anonfun$streamingSettings$6$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(
MongoHadoopBuild.scala:179)
        at MongoHadoopBuild$$anonfun$streamingSettings$6$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(
MongoHadoopBuild.scala:179)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:122)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.getOrElse(HashMap.scala:38)
        at MongoHadoopBuild$$anonfun$streamingSettings$6.apply(MongoHadoopBuild.
scala:179)
        at MongoHadoopBuild$$anonfun$streamingSettings$6.apply(MongoHadoopBuild.
scala:178)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$single$1.apply(IN
ode.scala:159)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$single$1.apply(IN
ode.scala:159)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:177)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:132)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anonfun$sbt$EvaluateSettings$$submitEvaluate$1.
apply$mcV$sp(INode.scala:64)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings.sbt$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:73)
        at sbt.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:69)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I am following this tutorial, however it's a bit outdated since the connector already supports the version 2.3 http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-hadoop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use gradle to build.  Gradle is the official way to build it now.  I'm waiting to remove the sbt stuff until the doc changes get pushed to that url.  The github page has the up to date instructions.